# Is it possible to programmatically set Principal in JSF+EJB

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, jaas, principal

I want to retrieve username using EJBContext.getCallerPrincipal()

```
public class GlobalInterceptor {

    @EJB
    private  AuditLogsEJB auditLogsEJB;

    @Resource
    private EJBContext context;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object auditLog(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception
    {  
          System.out.println(context.getCallerPrincipal());  //it outputs "ANONYMOUS"
    }
}
```

However I don't have any security realm, I don't have any <security-role> or <group-name> defined because the username/password is sent to a remote application to validate. But for convenience sake I still want to use the Principal class to get username and role.

Is there a way to programmatically set Principal(username and role) in JSF managed bean or any EJB, so that the interceptor can retrieve it? e.g.:

```
String role = authenticationWSPort.validate(username, password);
if(role != null) 
{
      Principal p = new Principal(username);
      p.getRoles.add(role);
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().blah-blah.blah-blah.addPrincipal(p);
      //I am looking for something similar to the 3 lines above
}
else
     // invalid username and password
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the correct way to do this is by setting up a realm, and using that.

Perhaps you could create & configure your own Realm implementation that would let you create users on the fly, prior to invoking request.login(username, password) in a servlet.

Or.

If you -really- want to futz with the underlying Request, it's possible, but it's application-server specific, and goes something like this, assuming you're in a tomcat (catalina) based container:

```
if (request instanceof RequestFacade) {
        Request unwrapped = null;
        RequestFacade rf = RequestFacade.class.cast(request);
        try {
            Field requestField = rf.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
            requestField.setAccessible(true);
            unwrapped = Request.class.cast(requestField.get(rf));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            unwrapped = null;
        }

        if (unwrapped != null) {
            unwrapped.setUserPrincipal(... your principal construction here ...);
        }
    }
```